# Шейдер видимый сквозь другие объекты?

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, hlsl

Можно ли средствами cg/hlsl, не используя Shader Graph, сделать шейдер, при применении которого в материал меша, его будет видно сквозь все другие объекты?

Хочу сделать метки видимые через все.

С написанием шейдеров знаком...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением было дописать пару строк вначале шейдера

```
Pass {
    Tags
    {
        "Queue" = "Transparent"
    }

    ZWrite Off
    ZTest Always
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

    //.....
```

Теперь выделение территории и метки у меня видны через все остальное.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: О! По мимо генерации начинает появляться некий геймплей 

Comment: Та там уже немало геймплея, просто там проблем намного меньше 